# hidden information in wxGrid

Tags: wxwidgets

I've got a wxGrid that I populate dynamically. I'd like to store some information with each row that shouldn't be displayed to the user. What is the best way to associate data with a row? Should I just create a hidden column or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Creating a hidden column is the fastest, but indeed a very ugly method. If you can justify the effort, then you should better create your own grid table base class. Your own *wxGridTableBase*-derived class can hold any information you need it to, without the need to show it in the grid. Unfortunately the documentation for that class is sparse or nearly non-existent.

For an example see the grid demo in the wxWidgets samples directory, specifically the *BugsGridTable* class. What you will notice is that you do not necessarily store the strings that the grid will display, but you can format your data in the *GetValue()* method. This can be a lot better, both in terms of memory consumption, and because you can change the format of displayed data on-the-fly.

The switch to a custom grid table base class has had a big impact on speed, memory consumption and functionality for the result set data grid of [FlameRobin](http://www.flamerobin.org), an administration tool for the Firebird relational database. You can always check out its source code for how we use wxGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Store the value in the row label using SetRowLabelValue and hide the row labels.